# Groovy - No signature of method

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin, groovyscriptengine

I am new to groovy scripting and currently I am working on a script which works as an addon for Atlassian Jira. The script was working fine in the older version, but we had upgraded Jira to version 7 and noticed that the script was no more running. I checked the errors and resolved them by changing the method calls as per the API changes, but still cannot get the script up and running.

I used the Script Runner for JIRA to check the error and it shows the following:

```
Error No signature of method: com.nimblestorage.jira.PopulateQaContactListener.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), find(), any(), wait(long, int), init(java.util.Map)
```

The stacktrace shows a list of 207 faults in the log:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.nimblestorage.jira.PopulateQaContactListener.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), find(), any(), wait(long, int), init(java.util.Map)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.RunScriptInvoker$run.call(Unknown Source)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.runScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy:459)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunner$runScript$5.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.runFileAsScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy:198)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.runFileAsScript(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy)
at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.UserScriptEndpoint.exec(UserScriptEndpoint.groovy:161)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:178)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:73)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:40)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:26)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.web.RedirectExternalCustomerToPortalFilter.doFilter(RedirectExternalCustomerToPortalFilter.scala:18)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:37)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:36)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:60)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:92)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:56)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:92)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.pagebuilder.PageBuilderFilter.doFilter(PageBuilderFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.doFilter(CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MauEventFilter.doFilter(MauEventFilter.java:32)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:79)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:40)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:41)
at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:70)
at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:78)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:31)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:39)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:39)
at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.startup.JiraStartupChecklistFilter.doFilter(JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:115)
at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92)
at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.gzip.JiraGzipFilter.doFilter(JiraGzipFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Please help me out here, I need a direction so as to where to look for in the code to resolve this issue.

```
Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Show us your script?

Comment: It would be impossible to imagine what you are trying to do without posting what you already have.

Comment: Looks like you're calling `main` on something without a method `main`... But that's as much as my crystal ball will show me... The rest is cloudy

Answer (score 0):

Well difficult to say without your script but stack trace is related to Nimble Storage Add-ons. Have you removed or upgraded this add-on after upgrading to JIRA 7?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and converted my "Heritage"-style listener to the modern syntax that does not inherit from `AbstractIssueEventListener`. For the most part, you can just copy the body of the `workflowEvent` method you defined in your listener and it will run with minor tweaks.